# How to process validated form

Tags: php

In a checkout form where input errors are returned to the same page, after all the validation is done I want to store inputs into a session and output on an order confirmation page. There error I am getting is that the form submits to the same page instead of another page.

Here is my input validation code

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    
    $firstnameErr = $emailErr = $addressErr = $postcodeErr = $cardnameErr =  $cardnumberErr = $expmonthErr = $expyearErr = $cvvErr = "";
    $firstname = $email = $address = $city = $town = $postcode = $cardname =  $cardnumber = $expmonth = $expyear = $cvv = "";
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     
    
    if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
        $firstnameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        // check if field contains only letters and spaces
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
      $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
      }
    
    }
    
    
      
    
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any JavaScript code in this question? All I see is PHP code...

Comment: No JavaScript code provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
 session_start();
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";
$error = false;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    $error = true;
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $error = true;
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $error = true;
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $error = true;
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
    $error = true;
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
       $error = true;
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
    $error = true;
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
     $error = true;
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

  if($error == false){
  $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
  $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['website'] = $website;

  header("location: order-page.php");

  }


}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="other") echo "checked";?> value="other">Other  
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

On the **order-page.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Retrieve data saved in session
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this only validates the data on the same page.  Once all fields have been successfully validated I want to send the user to a different order confirmation page.

Comment: I have updated the answer  to what I feel you need.

Comment: Thanks.  That code is for displaying the posted data on the new page.  Sorry if my question was not clear - the user is still on the page where the form is being validated. I don't know how to move to the next page with the form data.  I can put header location and a url at the end of the script but it does not send the form data.

Comment: Save the form data into `$_SESSION` and show it on the next page.

Comment: The form now submits directly to the new page without going through validation. The session works fine though - I can retrieve the submitted values on the new page. Need to stop the form submitting before all validation is done. Any ideas?